# Меню в Java Swing ?!

Tags: action, java, классы

Пишу простое приложение на java. 
При создании меню возник вопрос :

Для каждого пункта меню необходимо создать обработчик действия.
Почитал пример из Хорстманна. И возник вопрос - для каждого действия писать отдельный класс-наследник от AbstractAction или можно поступать например так :

```
fileMenu.add(new AbstractAction("Exit") 
{ 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }
});
```

Как правильно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если у вас обработка кода сводится до нескольких строк то создавать отдельный класс совсем не обязательно анонимные подойдут. если вам такой вариант не нравится (или не подходит) используйте листенеры:

```
class AbcFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public AbcFrame()
    {
        new JMenuItem("Help").addActionListener ( this );
        new JMenuItem("About").addActionListener ( this );
    }    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        // по event.getSource() определяем кто сгенерировал ивент
        // и обрабатываем 
    }
}
```

п.с. имхо удобнее 1ый вариант т.к. обработка определенного действия у вас находится в отдельном методе и не мешает удобочитаемости кода

Answer (score 1):

сейчас тоже с этим разбираюсь, похоже можно не создавать отдальные классы,
 а делать так как вы написали, 
судя по [примерам](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#event)

Comment: Ну вроде то можно  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html">тут</a> есть <a rel="nofollow" href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/ActionDemoProject/src/misc/ActionDemo.java">пример</a> где для каждого действия добросовестно создается отдельный класс.
Так вот и интересно как делать правильнее )

Comment: Да, точно, по всей видимости и так и так можно, но создание отдельных классов 
выглядит по удобнее и читабельнее и наверное так будет более правильнее.

Comment: я тоже так подумал. И пишу новый класс для каждого действия - в конечном счете так эффективнее, хоть и чуть больше кода.

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно на каждое действие делать класс. Можно сделать так к примеру:

```
JMenuItem b=new JMenuItem(xx[0]);
b.setName(xx[1]);
b.addActionListener(this);
m.add(b);
```

и public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
обрабатывать по имени

Answer (score 1):

У Хорстманна описаны обработчики события используя вложенные анонимные классы(он есть в вашем примере выше). Поэтому можно либо использовать анонимные вложенные классы для каждого обработчика события, либо сделать один и от него наследовать.
Советую еще раз внимательно прочитать про то как реализовывается обработчик событий у Хорстманна( том 1)